# Remote object: invalid field specified. Ensure that you use the full API name for any custom fields

Tags: apex, remote-objects

I am getting this weird error, when using remote object and I am not sure what is going on:

[image: invalid field specified. Ensure that you use the full API name for any custom fields]

this field exist in my salesforce object
[image]

I am successfully retrieving several fields, but when I add this one i get the error, I have tried retrieving using the shrothand

```
<apex:remoteObjectField name="AUD_Price__c" jsShorthand="AUD_Price"/>
```

and using

```
<apex:remoteObjectModel name="Product2" jsShorthand="P2" fields="Name,Id, AUD_Price__c">
```

I was thinking it could be a restriction in the field type, however from my current list that I am retrieving I have other currency and number fields.

What could be the issue that is causing this error?

Comment: Is it possible that your AUD_Price__c field comes from an unmanaged package? If so, you need to use a prefix to call the field.

Comment: Also check the FLS for the field for the profile

Comment: @MohithShrivastava You are right, this was from a site and it didnt had read access, this have fixed it

Comment: Added as answer .Please upvote or mark it answered so it helps others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is here because the FLS for the field has not been provided . Please note that remote objects by default respect CRUD/FLS settings configured by your salesforce admins